# DynamoDB table design pattern: catagorized data with utc time stamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm currently designing a DynamoDB pattern I don't know if I'm on the right track or not.

I have the following data I need to store into a DynamoDB table:

- deviceID (number)
- deviceLogType (string)
- timestamp (number) // timestsamp is in utc seconds
- other misc attributes

The primary query for this DynamoDB table is to query the data by both deviceID and deviceLogType over a time range. Is

**Partition Key** : `deviceLogType_deviceID`

**Sort Key** : `timestamp`

My questions are:

- Is the above design correct?
- Is it within the best practice to use composite key for partition key to represent hierarchical relations?

Comment: Do you ever need to search for "all deviceLogTypes for a given deviceID and time range" or "all deviceIDs for a given deviceLogType and time range"? If so, how many deviceLogTypes are there, and is that number ever going to grow?

Comment: which is the hierarchical relation more exactly?

Comment: @MatthewPope, No, I don't need to search for either. There's a fix number of deviceLogTypes.

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea, the hierarchical relation: deviceLogType -> deviceID

Answer (score 0):

```
deviceLogType_deviceID (hash key)
timestamp (sort key)
deviceID (I would keep this separate for future query possibilities)
deviceLogType (I would keep this separate for future query possibilities)
other misc attributes
```

Using this schema, you can use your current query and will open future possibilities for querying only by deviceId or deviceLogType (only add an index).

Composite key is indeed a good practice (best to have a separator which will not appear in both values), but not sure about which inheritance you mean.

But for example if we have AndroidDeviceLogType > DeviceLogType, best practise would be to store that value in deviceLogType in a serialised form (JSON in Base64 for example, or just plain JSON...).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work for the use case you have described.

It is acceptable to use a composite partition key. You cannot perform any hierarchical queries using partial matching on a partition key, but historically it had the added benefit of helping to prevent hot partitions. Hot partitions are now [a thing of the past](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-is-now-instant/), so you don't need to be concerned about that anymore.

There is only one possible problem I see. If you have more than one log entry with the same `deviceLogType_deviceID` and `timestamp`, the last one will overwrite all previous entries with the same timestamp. To avoid that, you can store the timestamp as an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string and append a UUID to the end of the timestamp to prevent primary key conflicts.